# Spring boot and cloudfoundry compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

What is the **highest version of spring boot** that can be used which is **compatible with cloud foundry**?

Is there any issue with 1.4.1 with cloudfoundry?
i have tested the application using 1.3.8 and that works.

What buildpacks version are needed?

Comment: We're not aware of any problem. Make sure your buildpack is up-to-date though. It would probably help if you explain the problem you're having instead.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll we are currently using 1.3.0 spring boot version but want to upgrade to the latest and i'm not aware of any resourses how to check compatibility for cloud foundry. but i want upgrade it to latest version possible.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll i have latest buildpacks installed already

Comment: Like I said, it works with the latest. We have plenty of Spring Boot 1.4 apps in prod on cloudfoundry. The general approach would be to upgrade since it should simply work.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneNicoll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.3 and earlier will work with any version of the Cloud Foundry Java Buildpack. Boot 1.4 and later require Java Buildpack 3.8 or later.

Comment: Thaks @ScottFrederick.